Proving that $c$ does not belong to the Mandelbrot Set
Problem: I want to prove that if $|f^{(m)}(0)| > |c| + 1$ for some $m$, then $c$ does not belong to the Mandelbrot set.
Answer: A point $c$ is in the Mandelbrot set if $f^{(m)}(0)$ remains bounded as $m \to \infty$. Where $f(z) = z^2 + c$.
We apply the inequality $(|A+B| \geq |A|-|B|)$ to the iteration:
$$
|f(z)| = |z^2 + c| \geq |z^2| - |c|
$$
Now, at some arbitrary iteration $m$, we have $|f^{(m)}(0)| > |c| + 1$. Then we have:
$$
|f^{(m+1)}(0)| = |(f^{(m)}(0))^2 + c| \geq |f^{(m)}(0)|^2 - |c| > (|c| + 1)^2 - |c| = |c|^2 + |c| + 1 > |c| + 1
$$
Here is how far I've gotten. I’m unsure if this proves anything. I want to conclude that this shows if $m$ goes to $\infty$, then the sequence $f^{(m)}(0)$ is unbounded. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

We can assume that $c \ne 0$, since otherwise $f^{(m)}(0) = 0$ for all $m$.
It is correct that $|f^{(m)}(0)| > |c| + 1$ implies
$$
 |f^{(m+1)}(0)|  >  |c|^2 + |c| + 1 > |c| + 1
$$
but that does not yet prove that $(f^{(n)}(0))_{n \ge m}$ is unbounded, only that it is bounded from below. But we can repeat the argument to the next iteration:
$$
\begin{align}
|f^{(m+2)}(0)| &> (|c|^2 + |c| + 1)^2 - |c| \\
&= |c|^4 + 2 |c|^3 + 3 |c|^2 + |c| + 1 \\
&> 3 |c|^2 + |c| + 1 \, .
\end{align}
$$
Continuing in this fashion one can show that
$$
|f^{(m+3)}(0)| > 5|c|^2 + |c| + 1 \, ,
$$
and generally
$$
|f^{(m+k)}(0)| > (2k-1)|c|^2 + |c| + 1
$$
for all positive integers $k$. It follows that $f^{(n)}(0) \to \infty$ for $n \to \infty$.

Thank you. I really appreciate your answer!
